# Use private feed with azure pipeline ends with error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

I'm new to AzureDevops and I'm trying to something.

- I have a project which produces a nuget package and I'm exposing it with a private azure feed.
- And I have another project that is using the previously created feed

Locally with Visual Studio everything is working fine. But now, I'm trying to use azure pipeline to restore nugets from the private feed but it ends with

> NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source

Please help, I was struggling for 2 days about this
Thanks

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore packages
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '********-3675-435f-******-2c889c224eb1/********-b859-84a7-a54c-***********'
```

- I tried to add the user agent as contributor in the feed permissions
- and tried to to disable Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines and release pipelines

Comment: Hi n07, i guess the problem is 401 access. Can you confirm by looking at logs in the task output? Where is your "other project" located? In the same organization? In general I would suggest to create a "Service connection" to the nuget feed, with your personal access token and before DotNetCoreCLI@2 Task use NuGetAuthenticate@1 Task with the name of that service connection for nuGetServiceConnections.

Comment: Thank you very much @MarioDietner your answer guided me to the solution. I initially created a project scoped feed instead of organizational feed.